# Dynamic jQuery Dialog Box

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

I come here a lot and find this place to be very useful. My first time posting and I hope someone could help me.

I have a page creating multiple links.
When you click on a link, it opens a specific dialog box pertaining to that link. That dialog contains a form with all data specific to that link id
But when I submit, it appears that data belonging to first link submits, whichever dialog box is opened.

When I click on a link, here is the code that opens and properly populate dialog according to the `$link.attr('href')`
The save button executes `$('#prefForm').submit();`
Now I got the feeling that when I click on a link, it opens all dialogs links, keeping them in the background, therefore creating multiple id prefForm so the first one for first link sends its data

I can't assign different ids as those forms are dynamically generated and id will be unknow.

Does anyone knows how to prevent other data to load only on demand and not all of them in the background?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#bidders td a').each(function() {
            var $link = $(this);
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
                .dialog({
                    autoOpen: false,
                    title: $link.attr('title'),
                    width: 600,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Cancel",
            className: 'cancelButtonClass',
            click: function() {
                $dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        },
        {
            text: "Save",
            className: 'saveButtonClass',
            click: function() { 
                 $('#prefForm').submit();
                 $dialog.dialog('close');
            }
        }
```

Comment: How you are opening your dialogs, by clicking or at document load all automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using .each() -  to load them all?

```
$('#bidders td a').each(function() {
```

Why not change it to .click()?

```
$('#bidders td a').click(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
       var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 600,
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        className: 'cancelButtonClass',
        click: function() {
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Save",
        className: 'saveButtonClass',
        click: function() { 
             $('#prefForm').submit();
             $dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. That made sense what you said, but that link no longer opens dialog. Only when each is invoked, the link opens dialog

Comment: click is not opening dialog, but opens the page. The problem is with the submit function. the id #prefForm is not unique since each loaded them all. Click made sense, but is not opening dialog box. It sends to full page

Comment: try using preventDefault() as I have updated above. It prevents hyperlinks from working (it wont load the page but (should) fire your desired script.

Comment: event.preventDefault();
does not open anything at all and won't fire popup either

Comment: OK. I found a solution and am posting. That might help another newbie like me
Icreated a unique id for each form
id="prefForm_$bidid"
I replaced the 
$('#prefForm').submit();
with
$(this).find('form').submit();

and that appears to submit correct form.

Answer (score 0):

You have now `.each` in the `$(document).ready(function() {` which means that you create `GET` for each matching element.

Maybe you could bind click event to each element and send `GET` and create dialog on the event?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#bidders td a').click(function() {
        var $link = $(this);
        var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            .load($link.attr('href') + ' #content')
            .dialog({
                autoOpen: false,
                title: $link.attr('title'),
                width: 600,
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        className: 'cancelButtonClass',
        click: function() {
            $dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Save",
        className: 'saveButtonClass',
        click: function() { 
             $('#prefForm').submit();
             $dialog.dialog('close');
        }
    }
```

Comment: click is not opening dialog, but opens the page. As you said, each gets them all since dialog content must be in background to load. Once I get them all, how do I send only the desired one?

Comment: OK. I found a solution and am posting. That might help another newbie like me I created a unique id for each form id="prefForm_$bidid" I replaced the $('#prefForm').submit(); with $(this).find('form').submit(); and that appears to submit correct form